# Forward all traffic on a specific interface to a IP:PORT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port

I currently debug apps on different devices. Most of the devices have a method to setup a proxy that I can supply it a IP and PORT to send all traffic to. One of the devices, Roku, does not have this ability.

Is it possible to setup a wifi hotspot using a USB adapter on my computer, and then somehow forward all traffic that connects to that adapter through a IP and port? This would be my local computer that is running a Charles debugging proxy. I was not sure if this is possible with something like socat or if setting up firewall rules would work?

Comment: Dunno about Charles or whatever, but this is called a _transparent proxy_.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a fumble solution but I think this could work pretty well in your situation. Nginx streams would allow you to take in data on your computer then send it to any server with any port. Example:

Roku connects to yourcomputer.ip:(roku port) nginx recives the data and sends it to placeyouwantittogoto.ip(any port you want)

From your question description I think you want to do exactly this.
I apologise if I have miss-understood your question.
Good luck and happy nerding!

Link to nginx streams setup and explanation https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: I think the problem is that since the Roku does not support proxy server configuration, you can't get it to point to yourcomputer.ip:port. its trying to connect to roku.com or whatever and Op wants to run that connection through their proxy. so they are looking for a way to connect the roku to a wireless device that automatically proxifies the traffic through their proxy server.